# Why does my waypoint not work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to learn waypoints.js. The problem is the my function runs directly on page load. And not on my waypoint. And I can't figure out why.

I would appriciate i anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong?

JS code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.filter_container').waypoint(function(direction) {
                  $('.filter_container').css('position', 'fixed');
                  $('.filter_container').css('top', '50px');
                  $('.filter_container').css('z-index', '5');
                  $('.filter_container').css('width', '100%');
                  $('.filter_container').css('left', '0');
                  $('.filter_container').css('border-radius', '0');
                  $('.filter-header-container').css('display', 'none');
                  $('.filter_container').css('padding', '0');
                  $('.filter_container h2').css('float', 'left');
                  $('.filter_container h2').css('display', 'inline');
                  $('.filter_container').css('height', '50px');
                  $('.filter_container h2').css('margin-top', '-10px');
                  $('.filter-form').css('margin-top', '0');
                }, {
                    offset:'50px'});
                });
```

All the jQuery code, runs on page load instead of whten .filter_container is 50px from the top of the window.